# How to add iAd in UIAlertview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, iad

I used iAd framework for add ad on screen. I done with this by below code.
but I want ad in UIAertview. When UIAlertview comes user should be view company ad in that.

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatesAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);             [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}


- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
          if (!self.bannerIsVisible) 
          {
              [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatesAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
              banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height); //rect, dx,dy
              [UIView commitAnimations];
              self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
          }
}
```

I know we can customized UIAlertview. But not getting how to add iAd view in that. If anyone know's help me.

Comment: You should not add subviews to a UIAlertView. Apple engineers have stated on numerous occasions at WWDC that this is bad and not officially supported.

Comment: For the love of UX, please do not do this!  IIRC, iAds need to be visible for 30 seconds to generate revenue anyway.

Comment: If you want iAd to appear in an "alert" sort of manner, use another class, and add it as a subview to that. https://github.com/eaigner/CODialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to create an ad for your own company? You wouldn't use iAd for this, as with iAd you have very little control over which advertisement is pushed to your banner. However you can make a new view with whatever you want in it (advertisement wise) and add it as a subview of your `UIAlertView`. Now I am saying you **CAN** do this, but you probably shouldn't. Modification of an alertView in this way will most likely be rejected by Apple.